# selenium python send_key error: list object has no attribute

Tags: python, selenium, key

Helo,

my xpath does validate in firePath but when I try to send _key I get an error.

```
userID = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='UserName']")

userID.send_keys('username')
```

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Can someone toss me a bone please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are getting a **List** of webElements with `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='UserName']")` which of course not a single element and does not have `send_keys()` method. use `find_element_by_xpath` instead. Refer to [this](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) api doc.

```
userID = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='UserName']")

userID.send_keys('username')
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of this:

```
userID = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='UserName']")

userID.send_keys('username')
```

try:

```
userID = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='UserName']")

userID.send_keys('username')
```

I had the same issues and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

`driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='UserName']").send_keys('username')`

find_element without `s`.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='UserName']").send_keys('username')

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your code with the following code because you like addressing the first component of your list, not whole list.

```
userID = driver.find_elements_by_ID('username')[0]

userID.send_keys('username')
```

or delete "s" from find_elements_by_ID such as follow:

```
userID = driver.find_element_by_ID('username')

userID.send_keys('username')
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem while using to input for Instagram, tried the time module to sleep for 2 seconds then it started working for me. Problem was that before loading the website bot starts to find that path and report errors.

```py
import time
time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when one tries to perform action on list instead of element. I was getting similar error when I was trying to click on button to submit credentials. I found the work around by emulating pressing enter key on keyboard. e.g. find any element on page using xpath/css, etc. and send enter key.
   `driver.find_element_by_id('test_id').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - so I just did:

```
userID[0].send_keys('username')
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

userID = driver.find_elements( By.XPATH, "//div[@title='Username']")
userID[0].send_keys('username')
```

Answer (score -2):

when we select multiple element we type **elements (s)**, its return a **list**. that have no "send_keys" single **element have no s**. that have "send_keys"

Comment: This has already been mentioned in in the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29957417/13525512