# Send_Keys in python selenium is not working in some specific website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I have found that the "Send_Keys" is not working for the following website due to the error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'".. Kindly note that I am using 'pycharm' editor

**https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=eu**

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[id='username']").send_keys("testusername")
```

But the same command is working perfectly when using for the following

**https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/**

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='name']").send_keys("testname")
```

Comment: Please refer to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957373/selenium-python-send-key-error-list-object-has-no-attribute

Comment: The first one calls `find_elements_by_css_selector`, which returns a _list_ of found elements.  The second one calls `find_element_by_css_selector`, which returns a single element.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[id='username']").send_keys("testusername")
```

retruns a list , and send_keys is a method of webelement and not a list. So to send value to specific element call that element from the list

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[id='username']")[0].send_keys("testusername")
```

On the other hand

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id='username']").send_keys("testusername")
```

finds the first webelement matching the xpath locator so sendkeys works